# How Does Find first child work in my scenario? - (Roblox Studio)

Tags: roblox

I am trying to create a script: when a rocket collides with a brick, money is given to the shooter. However, the script is not working, and I believe it is because of FindFirstChild.

The script so far:

```
    function touched(Hit)
        print(Hit)
        if Hit.Name == "Rocket" then
            print("Money")
            print(Hit.creator.Value)
            local Creator = Hit.creator.Value
            local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(Hit.creator.Value)
            if plr then
                print(plr)
                plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value = plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value + 10
            end
                end
            end



    script.Parent.Touched:Connect(touched)
```

When run, the script does not print anything past `local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(Hit.creator.Value)` leading me to believe that this is where the error is. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Your code for FindFirstChild looks fine. Are your rockets working properly? When you print out creator.Value, is the name the same as the player that fired the rocket?

Comment: Yea When you shoot a rocket at it, the part detects it but I think it dosnt have enough time to scan for The value so it calls it nill Cuase i tested if it had a value and it does and thats my username for roblox.

Comment: Oh and yea, The value is the same as the players name who fired it.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that the rocket is deleting itself too quickly, what you can do is make the rocket a model instead, and have the creator tag inside the model instead of the part.